# Log rotation/clearing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

How can I setup the automatic cleanup on test.log and development.log in ruby on rails?

Is there a setting to automatically delete dev and test logs on server start and tests run?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cleanup"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [ruby logger](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Logger.html) is on hand to help you out here - and it has default options for rotation.

Here's what I do:

In `environment.rb` we define our own logger

```
new_logger = Logger.new(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "log", "new_logger_#{RAILS_ENV}.log"), 'daily')
new_logger.formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
```

This creates our own loggers... with a formatter (so you get timestamps etc), with one per environment, and rotated daily.

Then in the initialization block we ask Rails to use this logger

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

  config.active_record.logger = new_logger
  config.action_controller.logger = new_logger

  #snip
end
```

You can obviously see the power here too to have different loggers for `active_record` and for `action_controller` - sometimes very useful!

Comment: Note: In Rails 3, your "initalisation block" is in development.rb, production.rb, etc.

Comment: Also, in Rails 3 your `RAILS_ROOT` is `Rails.root`, and `RAILS_ENV` is `Rails.env`. It looks like the Rails community is not into the caps-lock anymore?

Answer (score 16):

`rake log:clear` is a rake task that truncates all files that match `log/*.log` to zero bytes.
You could call it in your server start and run tests tasks.

Comment: +1 for th rake task. Similarly, you can also manually delete all log files on disk with `File.delete()` (be sure to also delete any rolled-over files ending in `.0`, `.1`, etc...). Then you can reset the logger with `@logger.reopen` and it will re-create the log file

Answer (score 1):

All script/server is, is a ruby script, im sure you could modify it to do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.rm File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), log, *.log)
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/server'
```

Answer (score 0):

In production environment, you really need SyslogLogger ( http://rails-analyzer.rubyforge.org/tools/files/lib/analyzer_tools/syslog_logger_rb.html ) , it lets you write to syslogd, which creansup,rotates your files in distributed setup.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting, I found that Rails initializers are loaded at the right point where you can truncate the file using the standard Ruby `File` class. I have this in *config/initializers/truncate_logs_on_server_start.rb*:

```
if MyRailsApp::Application.config.truncate_logs_on_server_start
  # Making an assumption here that we're logging to a file...
  File.open("log/#{ENV["RAILS_ENV"]}.log", "w") do |log_file|
    log_file.puts("Initializer truncate_logs_on_server_start reset the log file")
    log_file.puts
  end
end
```

You just then need to set `MyRailsApp::Application.config.truncate_logs_on_server_start` in *application.rb* and the various environments.